# Outer measure of product of sets

Tags: measure-theory, inequality

If  $A\subseteq R^n$ and $B\subseteq R^m$, such that $A \times B\subseteq R^{n+m}$
Prove that  $μ^{*}_{n+m}(A\times B)\leq μ^*_n(A)μ^*_m(B)$, where $μ^*_q$ is the outer measure of  $ \mathbb{R}^q $.

My attempt $A⊆⋃_iA_i,B⊆⋃_jB_j $, and since  $A \times B \subseteq ⋃_{i,j}A_iB_j$
I have the inequality (because of the outer measure monotocity) that states

$m^*_{n+m}(A \times B) \leq m^*_{n+m}(⋃_{i,j}A_iB_j)  $
But I don't think that is going to take me somewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think that the critical point you have to show is that the inequality holds for $A,B$ bounded. After that, one uses some standard argument on $\sigma$-finiteness.

Clearly, if $A,B$ are rectangles, the inequality holds trivially (in fact equality holds).

Now, for all $\varepsilon >0$, take some rectangles $A_i$, $B_j$ covering $A,B$ such that
$$\mu^*(A) \geq \sum_i \mu^*(A_i) - \varepsilon \qquad \mbox{  and } \qquad \mu^*(B) \geq \sum_j \mu^*(B_j) - \varepsilon$$

Then
$$A \times B \subset \bigcup_{i,j} A_i \times B_j$$
moreover
$$\mu^* \left( \bigcup_{i,j} A_i \times B_j \right) \leq \sum_{i,j} \mu^*(A_i \times B_j)  = \sum_{i,j} \mu^*(A_i) \mu^*(B_j) =$$
$$= \left( \sum_i \mu^*(A_i) \right) \left( \sum_j \mu^*(B_j) \right) \leq (\mu^*(A)+ \varepsilon )(\mu^*(B)+ \varepsilon )$$

Since $A,B$ have finite measure, you can send $\varepsilon \to 0$, and get the inequality.

Comment: You don't need the assumption that A, B have finite measure since otherwise the inequality is trivially true.