# outer measure and Cartesian product

Tags: real-analysis, outer-measure

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $B$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Note that the Cartesian product $\{(a, b) : a \in A, b\in B\}$ is then a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$. Show that $m^{*}_{n+m} (A \times B) \le m^{*}_n(A)m^{*}_m(B)$.

$m^*_n$ denotes an n-dimensional outer measure.

The definition of an outer measure is that $m^*_{n+m}(A \times B) = \inf \{\sum_{j \in J} \text{vol}(C_j) : A \times B \subseteq \bigcup_{j \in J} C_j\}$ and similarly $m^{*}_n =  \inf \{\sum_{i \in I} \text{vol}(A_i) : A  \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\}$ and $m^{*}_m(B) = \inf \{\sum_{k \in K} \text{vol}(B_k) : B  \subseteq \bigcup_{k \in K} B_k\}$.

I can also observe that the Cartesian product of a cover of $A$ and a cover of $B$ covers $A \times B$, but I am not sure how to proceed from here. I appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outer measure of product of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151795/outer-measure-of-product-of-sets)

Comment: Yes it answers my question, but I don't understand one thing there. How do we know that $\sum_{i,j} \mu^*(A_i \times B_j)  = \sum_{i,j} \mu^*(A_i) \mu^*(B_j) $ ?

Comment: @shk910 You should probably ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Remember that $A_i$ and $B_j$ are rectangles. What is their area?

Comment: $\text{vol}(A_i) = \prod_{k=1}^n(b_{i,k} - a_{i,k})$ given that $A_i = \{(x_1, ..., x_n): x_k \in (a_{i,k}, b_{i,k}) \}$, and similarly, $\text{vol}(B_j) = \prod_{k=1}^n(b_{j,k} - a_{j,k})$, but I am not sure  about $\text{vol}(A_i \times B_j)$.